# AspectJ ProceedingJoinPoint.getArgs when method args are null

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I was looking at the [Javadocs for ProceedingJoinPoint/JoinPoint](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs%28%29) in AspectJ, but they don't seem to tell me what the expected behavior is for method `getArgs` is when null values are passed as one or more of the arguments.  I am assuming I will get a value for each defined parameter, including nulls when appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will get back a null for the appropriate indexed argument value:

for eg, if the your 2nd argument is null calling `pjp.getArgs()[1]` will return null.